# What happens when multiple "when this creature dies" triggers happen at the same time?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In Magic the Gathering, If I have [Gate to the Afterlife](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGate%20to%20the%20Afterlife%5d) and [Shadows of the Past](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShadows%20of%20the%20Past%5d) on the battlefield and one of my creatures die which ability activates first?  Would I have to scry first or would I have to heal/draw/discard first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both capacities will trigger in the same time. You choose the one to apply first. (you put them on the stack in the order that you want)

> 603.3b If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered abilities they control on the stack in **any order they choose.**

APNAP order is Active player/non active player order. This means that effects from the active player, the one who's turn it is, get put on the stack first, in the order they choose, then the next player in turn order and so on. The last thing put on the stack is the first to resolve, so the person who's turn is farthest away will have their triggers resolve first.

Comment: It's usually considered pertinent to quote the specific paragraphs of the rules which back up your answer. In this case, it's 603.3b. I took the liberty of adding it to your answer.

Comment: Do we also need to define APNAP order? I don't have a good feel for how accessible the acronym is.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus, yes.  The OP is not familiar with the stack, so I would assume they are not familiar with APNAP.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus I read up about APNAP order and from what I could gather it would pretty much mean that my opponents triggered abilities (If he/she had any) would resolve before my triggered abilities would resolve.  Is this correct?

Comment: @atlster455 if it's your turn, yes.  The player whose turn it is puts their triggers on the stack first, which means that other players' triggers resolve first.